# ZXing problem when find qr code that does not know

Tags: iphone, objective-c, qr-code, zxing

I have a question ...
I am using ZXing lib to recognize two types of QRCode (for
iphone application)
everything works fine ....
I use this method to analyze the results:

```
- (void)zxingController:(ZXingWidgetController*)controller didScanResult:(NSString *)result {

    if([result isEqualToString:@QRCODERESULT_TYPPE_01])
    {
        ...CASE 01
    }
    else if([result isEqualToString:@QRCODERESULT_TYPPE_02])
    {
        ... CASE 02
    }
}
```

This code works fine if I find a QRCode type 01 or 02 but when I try with another QRCode not know the controller is still some green squares ...
how can I reset the controller when it reads a QRCode I do not care?
txy

Comment: what is a green square? you need to provide more information. based on your current code, it should work perfectly fine.

Comment: my code has to find only two types of QRCode. The problem is when you find a QRCode but it is not the kind I want.
this method is invoked:
(void)zxingController:(ZXingWidgetController*)controller didScanResult:(NSString *)result
if you can not find the QRCode I will see the green squares

Comment: I want is to discard the QRCode not interest me and i have analyze only my (2) qrcode types. how do I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dismiss the qr scanning controller regardless of whether the scanned QR code is the one you want or not.

```
- (void)zxingController:(ZXingWidgetController*)controller 
          didScanResult:(NSString *)result {

    // always dismiss the qr controller
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    if (qr code is of type 1) {
        // do something if qr 1
    }
    else if (qr code is of type 2) {
        // do something with qr 2
    }
}
```

Comment: so I have not solved my problem: When I meet a QRCode
that is not my type, on overlayView I see some green squares (the
QRCode analyzed) and do not go away ... my QRCode reader, it's like
blocked: no longer recognizes QRCode of any kind!